# How to import image with no extension

Tags: feeds

Im scraping a website, where the images has no extension, like:
http://www.website.com/image/media/42633

If i manually create a node at put the above link in external image link, via filefield sources, its fine.
The file is downloaded and inserted correct.

But if i use Feed and insert the same link, i get the error "The file 42633 has an invalid extension"

Is there any way i can make Feed, ignore the extension ?

Comment: Found the answer to my question here:
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/177888/how-to-import-image-using-feeds-which-doesnt-have-a-correct-file-extension?rq=1